# Why line motion is identity?

Tags: analysis

I am trying to intuitively understand some things about functions behaviour.

First, what seems weird is the fact, that to move graph of some function in positive direction, along the X axis on some value, that value need to be **subtracted** from the argument of the function, while, to move plot in positive direction along the Y axis on some value, that value need to be **added** to the function.

I was wondering, that maybe it is because of choose coordinate system, and to make things take their places, I need just make X axis directs from left to right, but this is wrong, since "left", "right" are relative terms, while "internal" direction of the axis, i.e. the direction where each variable value is higher than previous is absolute, and does not depends how someone look on it.

Second: it is also weird, that line's $y = kx + b$, or with rotation point $y = k(x - x_0) + y_0$, motion seems to be relative: for example, for $k=1$ it is impossible to determine whether line is moved "right" or "top", either "bottom" or "left".

What I understand for sure, that this is because of line's infiniteness. If line was finite, at least from one side, i.e. be a ray or a segment, there will not be the problem with right-top and left-bottom motion.

In case with Hyperbola or parabola, for example, one can determine whether it moves horizontally, or vertically.

Perhaps, such motion non-relativity somehow related with function's range, because $y=kx+b$ has infinite range $R=(-∞,∞)$, while $y = x^2$ $R = [0,∞)$, $y = 1/x$ $R = (-∞,0)∪(0,∞)$, $y = \sqrt{x}$ $R = [0,∞)$, $y = \sin(x)$ $R = [-1, 1]$  and so on.

Yet, range, seems to be not an intuitive explanation, I think there is something more fundamental.

Comment: My advice is not to overthink this. If you know how to do the mathematical manipulations properly, then you're doing fine. You'll just have to train your intuition so that your subjective, mental notions of "left", "right", "top" and "bottom" are consistent with the mathematical manipulations.

Comment: @LeeMosher, I am not studying for school, university, job or other material profit. I am interested in mathematics, so I want to understand anything I want and can. As for subjectiveness, at least, relatively to directions in current topic - as I wrote, I consider it

Comment: Look at $f(x)$ and its value when $x =0$ I.e $f(0)$. The function $f(x-2)$ is $f(x)$ shifted right by 2 since you will get the value $f(0)$ when $x=2$, not when $x=-2$.

Comment: If you rewrite $y = k(x-x_0) + y_0$ as $y - y_0 = k(x-x_0)$ then you can see that you're really acting on $x$ and $y$ in exactly the same way.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff, yeah, I already though exactly about it. But $y-y_0 = k(x-x_0)$ does not show the function value, it does not show "y". It shows function value, that is less on $y_0$, i.e. "$y$" - "$y_0$"

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Any 2-D graph (this concept is generalizable to higher dimensions) is actually the locus of points $(x,y)$ which satisfy $P(x,y)=0$ for some function $P$. Now a shift in origin to $(a,b)$ changes the graph to $P(x-a,y-b)=0$ [try to think why this is true]. Now can you see why the equation for translation of a straight line when origin is shifted is like that? (@NicholasTodoroff 's comment aptly describes the specific case when $P$ is the function defining a straight line)

The key concept that you should take away from this is that instead of thinking of graphs as finding $w$ given $(x, y, z,...)$ using $w=f(x,y,z,..)$, try to think of them as finding all points $(w,x,y,z,...)$ that satisfy a particular relation. Because when you try to think of implicit functions, in some cases you may not be able to solve the equation for any one variable. In such situations, you will realize that the plot of that implicit function is actually the locus of all points which satisfy a particular relation.